# Arbitrating Jersey endpoints based on Accept headers: what when no Accept header is given?

Tags: java, annotations, jersey, dropwizard, http-accept-header

Suppose I have two endpoints that look like this:

```
@GET
@Path("/blah")
@Produces(MIME_TYPE_1)
public Thing getThing() {
    ....
}

@GET
@Path("/blah")
@Produces(MIME_TYPE_2)
public OtherThing getOtherThing() {
    ....
}
```

This works very well for arbitrating which method gets invoked based on the `Accept` header that the client sends.

The problem I'm having is that if the client misses off the `Accept` header entirely, I (for some reason) get the second method invoked, and I want it to be the first one.

There's an additional complication, which is that this is feeding automatically into Swagger documentation, and I don't want extra MIME types to appear in the documentation, so I don't want (for instance) to add `*/*` to the types accepted by the first method.

(This is using Dropwizard and Jersey 1.x, though I am still interested to hear solutions based on Jersey 2.x, to which we may upgrade before long.)

Comment: You _might_ be able to filter the request and modify the `Accept` header before Jersey queries it. I don't think it would work with a `ContainerRequestFilter`  but it might with a `ServletFilter`.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the quality factor parameter in the `@Produces` annotation:

```
@GET
@Path("/blah")
@Produces("application/json; q=0.6")
public Thing getThing() {
....
}

@GET
@Path("/blah")
@Produces("application/xml; q=1")
public OtherThing getOtherThing() {
....
}
```

If a client does not send the 'Accept:' header in the request, the web server will execute `getOtherThing()` because it has a higher quality factor than `getThing()`.

*Disclaimer:* this works with RestEasy, but I cannot guarantee it will work with Jersey.

The quality factor parameter is part of [RFC 2616 (14.1)](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) 
You can find more info about this feature in RestEasy [here](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.9.Final/userguide/html/JAX-RS_Content_Negotiation.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this solution which also works with Apache CXF!